# Create dynamic labels for a field in a formset

Tags: django, django-forms, formsets

I have a form as follows

```
class InstructorCourseCertificationForm(forms.Form):
    Course = forms.BooleanField()
    SubjectExpert = forms.BooleanField(label='Subject Expert')
```

I need to create a formset of these and set the label of the Course field dynamically depending on the list of courses I have.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience where I need to have dynamic fields, I usually ended up storing the data in the database and then according to the data in the db, generate dynamic forms. In other words, I do not create `forms.Form` based class, which I later customize, but I create a class from scratch using python's `type` function.

I think this might be clearer in an example. Lets say you have a model `Course` with a `name` field in it:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

So then you can create a form from scratch by adding a method to the model:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    ...
    def certificate_form_class(self):

        # assuming the name can only have spaces
        # if not, then more normalizing has to be done
        form_name = self.name.title().replace(' ', '')

        bases = (forms.Form,)

        fields = {
            'Course': forms.BooleanField(label=self.name),
            'SubjectExpert': forms.BooleanField(label='Subject Expert')
        }

        form_class = type(form_name, bases, fields)

        return form_class
```

Then you can use this as follows:

```
course = Course.objects.get(...)
certificate_form_class = course.certificate_form_class()
certificate_form = certificate_form_class()
# use it as a regular form
```

One might argue that at this point you are mixing forms and models, in which case you can make a helper function in your `forms.py` which will take an instance of the `Course` model and then create a certificate form out of out. But either way, the idea is identical.

One caveat though is that at this point, you do not have a guarantee that the fields are going to be in order. In that case you should use `OrderedDict` from `collections` instead of `dict` (`{}`) for defining the fields.

Not sure how well this method plays out with `FormSets` but maybe it can give you some ideas.